# Can't add service reference to net tcp wcf service

Tags: wcf, tcp, nettcpbinding

I have a WCF service hosted on my local machine as windows service. Now I'm trying to add a service reference in the client (again on my local dev machine) but I'm getting an error

> Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved:
>   'net.tcp://localhost:8523/Service1'. Could not connect to
>   net.tcp://localhost:8523/Service1. The connection attempt lasted for a
>   time span of 00:00:02.0011145. TCP error code 10061: No connection
>   could be made because the target machine actively refused it

I checked that the Windows firewall doesn't block port 8523. I even created a new rule in Windows firewall to allow run 8523 port. But when I'm running `netstat -sp tcp` I can't seem to find port 8523. But I can see Serice1 service's state is set to START in Services. This is the config files

Service Library

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <services>
    <service name="WcfServiceLibrary1.Service1">
      <endpoint 
           address="" 
           binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
           contract="WcfServiceLibrary1.IService1">
         <identity>
           <dns value="localhost" />
         </identity>
      </endpoint>
      <endpoint 
           address="mex" 
           binding="mexTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
           contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      <host>
        <baseAddresses>
          <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:8523/Service1" />
        </baseAddresses>
      </host>
    </service>
  </services>
  <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior name="">
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" />
        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Config in the windows service project looks identical.

Comment: Is that service, with identical configuration, working as expected if it's hosted in a console application? Did you check the event log for possible error messages from the windows service? You could also try to completely disable the firewall, just to make sure that it does not create trouble.

Comment: once you start the service are you sure it doesn't stop again through an error (Clemens suggestion with the event log will show that up). Refreshing the services view may show it has stopped again

Comment: @Clemens I checked event logs, no error message exists. It just shows up information that service successfully started. I disabled windows firewall completely, unfortunately still got the same error.

Comment: @RichardBlewett As I said in above comment, Service is running succesfully, and remains running without any problem.

Comment: Just because I can't see 8523 port in the active tcp connection lists, while my service is running, and I can see no error message in the event log, is that possible that something wrong with configuration, and it prevents service to run under 8523 port ??? Is there any way to see what port is running under my service, from Services ?

Comment: Just checked your netstat command. You have to call `netstat -ap tcp` to also see the listening connections.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Michael, this is a net.tcp binding that I typically use for a WCF service.

```
    <bindings>
        <netTcpBinding>
            <binding name="TcpBinding"
                     receiveTimeout="Infinite"
                     sendTimeout="Infinite"
                     maxBufferSize="2147483647"
                     maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
                <reliableSession inactivityTimeout="Infinite"/>
                <security mode="None"/>
            </binding>
        </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>
```

Try to add it to your configuration:

```
<service name="WcfServiceLibrary1.Service1">   
    <endpoint    
        address=""    
        binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="TcpBinding"   
        contract="WcfServiceLibrary1.IService1">   
    ...
```

Also, my services are running under `ServiceAccount.LocalSystem`.

Check

> netstat -**ap** tcp

if the service is listening.

EDIT: my Service class below. Note that the current directory of the windows service is set programatically to the [BaseDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.basedirectory.aspx), i.e. the directory of the executable.

```
public class Service : ServiceBase
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory);
        ServiceBase.Run(new Service());
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: Sorry for late response, tried it as well Clemens, but still can't seem to create client for service.

Comment: And do you see the service listening on port 8523?

Comment: Nope Clemens, thats the problem, I can't seem that port 8523 is running, so I changed the windows service with Console application, in particular, now Console Application is hosting service, and this works as expected, but I can't understand why, because both - windows service and console application are using same dll's of service and same configuration. So why I can host my service using Console Application but can't host it via Windows Service ? Any clues ?

Comment: Is the service running under ServiceAccount.LocalSystem?

Comment: well currently it's running under NetworkService account, but I followed your approach, and changed it to run under Local System, but nothing changed. I've even changed it to run under my account ( I'm admin on my dev machine ) but no luck so far.

Comment: Michael, take a look at the extended sample code in my answer. In  the Main method of my ServiceBase-dericed class i set the current working directory. Otherwise the service won't find its configuration file.

Comment: I've included config files all over the place, in windows service application, in the bin folder ( with WindowsService1.exe file ), same config file resists in the Service project itself ( again in the bin/Debug I've included config's as well ). Do you think this is still necessary ?

Comment: AFAIK a Windows service uses C:\Windows\System32 as current working directory by default, no matter where it is installed. So you **must** programatically set the cwd to that directory that contains your config file. This is usually the same directory as where the executable resides, i.e. AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory

Comment: Michael, are you still trying to solve this, i.e. did you try to set the service's cwd?

Comment: Nope, sorry for making you wait for my response. We decided to host it under IIS 7. But I'll try it as soon as I have free time, I'm curious as well, what was the problem. Thanks for support.

Answer (score 1):

You've specified a behavior but haven't given it a name.  Give the behavior a name and point to it using behaviorConfiguration in your service.

```
<service name="WcfServiceLibrary1.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="svc1behavior">
```

...

```
<serviceBehaviors>
<behavior name="svc1behavior">
  <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" />
  <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
</behavior>
</serviceBehaviors>
```

Comment: if you're using .NET4 you don;t need to name behavior blocks-an unnamed behavior block acts as a default behavior configuration for services

Answer (score 0):

Check that Net.Tcp listener adapter service is running (although if it works while hosting the service in console application, it should be running).

To find the port your service is using,

1. Open Task Manager
2. Select View -> Select Columns -> Check PID -> OK
3. Find your service process name, note the PID
4. Run the followind command from the command prompt: `netstat -ano | findstr *PID*`

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue. After a lot of troubleshooting I found out I was missing a reference to the service in Web.config in the service project, so I added this to Web.config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <services>
    <service name="serviceName" behaviorConfiguration="BasicServiceBehavior" >
      <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
      <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicServiceBasicHttpBinding" contract="(I<nameofservice>)"/>
    </service>
  </services>
</system.serviceModel>
```

After this a rebuilt the solution (which created the interface) and republished. Then I could finally add a service reference from my other project.