# wcf failed to add a service. service metadata may not be accessible

Tags: wcf, nettcpbinding

i am new in wcf.i have simple wcf service for like calculator for add,substract,muliply,division etc. i have two endpoint in my service config file. one is basicHttpBinding and another one is netTcpBinding. when i am hitting f5 then wcf test client appear and showing the error **wcf failed to add a service. service metadata may not be accessible** but if i off the netTcpBinding and mex for netTcpBinding and hit f5 then wcf test client can invoke the service. here is my config entry. so please have a look and tell me why i am getting error for netTcpBinding and how to fix it.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All Rights Reserved.-->
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <services>
            <service name="MyTcpActivation.CalculatorService" behaviorConfiguration="CalculatorServiceBehavior">

                <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="PortSharingBinding" 
                contract="MyTcpActivation.ICalculator"/>

                <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>




                <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="MyTcpActivation.ICalculator" />
                <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>             
            </service>
        </services>
        <bindings>
            <netTcpBinding>
                <binding name="" portSharingEnabled="true">
                    <security mode="None"/>
                </binding>
            </netTcpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <!--For debugging purposes set the includeExceptionDetailInFaults attribute to true-->
        <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior name="CalculatorServiceBehavior">
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
    </system.serviceModel>
    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true"/></system.web></configuration>
```

please guide me where to fix in config file as a result there should no issue whatever binding i use. thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8957158/cant-add-service-reference-to-net-tcp-wcf-service

Answer (score 0):

I think ... if you have two "IMetadataExchange" endpoints, then you need to provide different addresses.  For example:

```
        <service name="MyTcpActivation.CalculatorService" behaviorConfiguration="CalculatorServiceBehavior">

            <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="PortSharingBinding" contract="MyTcpActivation.ICalculator"/>
            <endpoint address="mex1" binding="mexTcpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>

            <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="MyTcpActivation.ICalculator" />
            <endpoint address="mex2" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>             
        </service>
```

Comment: i change the name like mexi & mex2 but still have the same issue.

Comment: Perhaps you could check the WCF Trace File to make sure the service is starting up correctly with both endpoints.  Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: i copied the xml code in config file like traceListener but no log file created.